# Create a map based on fasterxml jackson ObjectMapper and Response InputStream

Tags: java, json, parsing, playframework, jackson

I'm new at the fasterxml Jackson library, in fact I used to work with codehaus (1.x version of the library). to retrieve informations from an InputStream and stock it in a map we used this code:

```
Map objects = getObjectMapper().readValue(is, Map.class);
```

(with "is" is the `InputStream` we get from the response)
now that I'm changing to fasterxml version, I don't know how to do that, I tried to work with a `JsonNode` instead:

```
Map objects = (Map) json.get("_children");
```

with `_children` is a `LinkedList` contained in the `JsonNode`, and json is the Json we get from the response.

Comment: What is it that is stopping you from doing it the same way as before? `ObjectMapper.readValue(InputStream, Class)` is still there in Jackson 2... http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.Class)

Comment: But for reference, to map your `JsonNode` object to a POJO you would use `ObjectMapper.treeToValue(JsonNode, Class)`.

Comment: @Sam I tried to use the readValue method as used before, but I have a JsonMappingException: with this error message
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class java.util.Map